How to hide console application into Tray?
I want my console application to be hidden in the system tray after it starts. When working with a GUI application, I used TTrayIcon, and it worked without any problems. For the console application, I used the ShowWindow function with SW_HIDE and TNotifyIconData to create an icon in the tray, but I encountered a problem with the console icon still appearing in the Windows taskbar.
procedure HideShowConsoleWindow(isShowForm: Boolean);
var
  Style: LongInt;
  app: THandle;
begin
  app := GetConsoleWindow;
  Style := GetWindowLong(GetConsoleWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE);
  if isShowForm then
  begin
    SetWindowLong(app, GWL_EXSTYLE, Style or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW and not WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
    ShowWindow(app, SW_HIDE);
  end
  else
  begin
    SetWindowLong(app, GWL_EXSTYLE, Style and not WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW or WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
    ShowWindow(app, SW_SHOW);
  end;
end;

procedure AddTrayIcon;
var
  NotifyIconData: TNotifyIconData;
begin
  FillChar(NotifyIconData, SizeOf(TNotifyIconData), 0);
  NotifyIconData.cbSize := SizeOf(TNotifyIconData);
  NotifyIconData.Wnd := GetConsoleWindow;
  NotifyIconData.uID := 1;
  NotifyIconData.uFlags := NIF_ICON or NIF_MESSAGE or NIF_TIP;
  NotifyIconData.uCallbackMessage := $0400 + 1;
  NotifyIconData.hIcon := LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
  StrPCopy(NotifyIconData.szTip, 'My Console App');
  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, @NotifyIconData);
end;

Is there any way to hide the console application from the taskbar and add it to the system tray?

You don't own the console window, it doesn't even belong to your process. You show not be trying to manipulate it. A console app is the wrong choice for this task.

You never check a function's result - neither for Shell_NotifyIcon(), nor for SetWindowLong(). Functions may fail, as per their documentations. Why a console program to being with and not a GUI program without a single window?

The Shell_NotifyIcon() returns true, and I can see the icon in the tray. The SetWindowLong() does not return 0, and if I understand correctly, this means that the function was successful.

The tray can also be called the "notification area".

Cannot reproduce using Delphi 7 on Windows 7x64: my program succeeds in hiding both the console window and its task button:
program HideConsoleWindow;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

const
  SW_HIDE= 0;
  user32= 'user32.dll';
  kernel32= 'kernel32.dll';

type
  HWND= type LongWord;
  BOOL= LongBool;

  function GetConsoleWindow(): HWND; stdcall; external kernel32 name 'GetConsoleWindow';
  function GetForegroundWindow(): HWND; stdcall; external user32 name 'GetForegroundWindow';
  function SetForegroundWindow( h: HWND ): BOOL; stdcall; external user32 name 'SetForegroundWindow';
  function ShowWindow( h: HWND; nCmdShow: Integer ): BOOL; stdcall; external user32 name 'ShowWindow';

var
  hConsole, hFore: HWND;

begin
  hConsole:= GetConsoleWindow();
  if hConsole<> 0 then begin
    if SetForegroundWindow( hConsole ) then begin
      hFore:= GetForegroundWindow();
      if hFore<> 0 then begin
        ShowWindow( hFore, SW_HIDE );
        // Task button should be gone also in recent Windows versions.
      end else begin
        // No foreground window available - still try to set window.
        ShowWindow( hConsole, SW_HIDE );
      end;
    end else begin
      // Console wasn't brought to foreground - still try to set window.
      ShowWindow( hConsole, SW_HIDE );
    end;
  end else begin
    // Couldn't get console window.
  end;
end.

You shouldn't fiddle with GWL_EXSTYLE at all. And you should be aware of that if you start this program in an existing console you'll also hide that console window - maybe that's something you don't want to do, as it still lives on and then you're only left with killing its process.

When I use ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE); the console minimizes to the Windows taskbar.

That's why I mentioned my Windows and Delphi version. My code has been posted before and more recent answers experience the same (mis)behavior as you and suggest first issuing SetForegroundWindow( hConsole ) to then use GetForegroundWindow()'s handle to hide to.
